# Cannot log in with my user on ubuntu anymore

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a problem regarding logging in into ubuntu...I did something, I don't know what but I cannot login anymore.

Sudo, does not work, ll, ls, nothing...this is what I get from the command line after I got in by using CTRL+ALT+F3 in the login window

I have attached a photo...

Does anybody have a clue how can I restore what I have done?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you seem still logged-in but just have messed-up your path? Give the full path to each command you need and edit your .bashrc to include /usr and /bin and /usr/bin again. `/usr/bin/vi ~/.bashrc` might do the trick, if you are familiar with vi (or use nano instead of vi)

Comment: You messed up your profile and shell files, most likely. You should be able to restore them with basic functionality from `/etc/skel`

Comment: thank you anyway! I resolved the issue...I wrote it down to the answer

Answer (score 0):

ok...what I did was the following:

1. I have edited the file /etc/profile.d/maven.sh (because I dropped an "i" inside that script)
2. executed this command: export PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
3. executed export PATH="$PATH:/bin"

after all this commands all the ubuntu commands started working and I could login again...